# post updates to twitter

Tags: c#

to post updates to twitter i am using the following code.

```
OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
tokens.AccessToken = // My access token //;
tokens.AccessTokenSecret = // My access token secret //;
tokens.ConsumerKey = // My consumer key //;
tokens.ConsumerSecret = // My consumer secret//;
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatus> tweetResponse = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "Hello, #Twitterizer");
```

Can any one help me with code to post status updates to twitter

Comment: This might help: [Update to Twitter](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Using-OAuth-to-Send-Updates-to-Twitter-Using-C.aspx)

Comment: Probably not a good idea to post those secret keys to SO- I have removed them for you.  If those were mock data let me know and I'll revert the change.

Comment: thank u ,its just dummy application ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you also need to register yours app as read/write (default is readonly) ,

Or you would always receive the 401 error code.

Good luck.

**UPDATE:**

Ok , This is my code.

First is the Utility class , I think you could found a lot of such method in the internet.

```
class Auth {
        const string REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
        const string ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
        const string AUTHORIZE_URL = "https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

        private Random random = new Random();

        public string ConsumerKey { get; private set; }
        public string ConsumerSecret { get; private set; }
        public string RequestToken { get; private set; }
        public string RequestTokenSecret { get; private set; }
        public string AccessToken { get; private set; }
        public string AccessTokenSecret { get; private set; }
        public string UserId { get; private set; }
        public string ScreenName { get; private set; }

        public Auth(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret) {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
            ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
        }

        public Auth(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret, string userId, string screenName) {
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
            ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
            AccessToken = accessToken;
            AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSecret;
            UserId = userId;
            ScreenName = screenName;
        }

        public void GetRequestToken() {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters = GenerateParameters("");
            string signature = GenerateSignature("", "GET", REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, parameters);
            parameters.Add("oauth_signature", UrlEncode(signature));
            string response = HttpGet(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, parameters);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = ParseResponse(response);
            RequestToken = dic["oauth_token"];
            RequestTokenSecret = dic["oauth_token_secret"];
        }

        public string GetAuthorizeUrl() {
            return AUTHORIZE_URL + "?oauth_token=" + RequestToken;
        }

        public void GetAccessToken(string pin) {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters = GenerateParameters(RequestToken);
            parameters.Add("oauth_verifier", pin);
            string signature = GenerateSignature(RequestTokenSecret, "GET", ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, parameters);
            parameters.Add("oauth_signature", UrlEncode(signature));
            string response = HttpGet(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, parameters);
            Dictionary<string, string> dic = ParseResponse(response);
            AccessToken = dic["oauth_token"];
            AccessTokenSecret = dic["oauth_token_secret"];
            UserId = dic["user_id"];
            ScreenName = dic["screen_name"];
        }

        public string Get(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters2 = GenerateParameters(AccessToken);
            foreach (var p in parameters)
                parameters2.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
            string signature = GenerateSignature(AccessTokenSecret, "GET", url, parameters2);
            parameters2.Add("oauth_signature", UrlEncode(signature));
            return HttpGet(url, parameters2);
        }

        public string Post(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters2 = GenerateParameters(AccessToken);
            foreach (var p in parameters)
                parameters2.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
            string signature = GenerateSignature(AccessTokenSecret, "POST", url, parameters2);
            parameters2.Add("oauth_signature", UrlEncode(signature));
            return HttpPost(url, parameters2);
        }

        private string HttpGet(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url + '?' + JoinParameters(parameters));
            WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            stream.Close();
            return result;
        }

        string HttpPost(string url, IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JoinParameters(parameters));
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
            Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            reqStream.Close();
            WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            resStream.Close();
            return result;

        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> ParseResponse(string response) {
            Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (string s in response.Split('&')) {
                int index = s.IndexOf('=');
                if (index == -1)
                    result.Add(s, "");
                else
                    result.Add(s.Substring(0, index), s.Substring(index + 1));
            }
            return result;
        }

        private string JoinParameters(IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            bool first = true;
            foreach (var parameter in parameters) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.Append('&');
                result.Append(parameter.Key);
                result.Append('=');
                result.Append(parameter.Value);
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }

        private string GenerateSignature(string tokenSecret, string httpMethod, string url, SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            string signatureBase = GenerateSignatureBase(httpMethod, url, parameters);
            HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
            hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UrlEncode(ConsumerSecret) + '&' + UrlEncode(tokenSecret));
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signatureBase);
            byte[] hash = hmacsha1.ComputeHash(data);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }

        private string GenerateSignatureBase(string httpMethod, string url, SortedDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.Append(httpMethod);
            result.Append('&');
            result.Append(UrlEncode(url));
            result.Append('&');
            result.Append(UrlEncode(JoinParameters(parameters)));
            return result.ToString();
        }

        private SortedDictionary<string, string> GenerateParameters(string token) {
            SortedDictionary<string, string> result = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
            result.Add("oauth_consumer_key", ConsumerKey);
            result.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
            result.Add("oauth_timestamp", GenerateTimestamp());
            result.Add("oauth_nonce", GenerateNonce());
            result.Add("oauth_version", "1.0");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                result.Add("oauth_token", token);
            return result;
        }

        public string UrlEncode(string value) {
            string unreserved = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~";
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            foreach (byte b in data) {
                if (b < 0x80 && unreserved.IndexOf((char)b) != -1)
                    result.Append((char)b);
                else
                    result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)b));
            }
            return result.ToString();
        }

        private string GenerateNonce() {
            string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(8);
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
                result.Append(letters[random.Next(letters.Length)]);
            return result.ToString();
        }

        private string GenerateTimestamp() {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        }
    }
```

This is console app , u can use it to get token by pincode

```
class Program {
    const string CONSUMER_KEY = "yours CONSUMER_KEY";
    const string CONSUMER_SECRET = "yours CONSUMER_SECRET";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Auth auth = new Auth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);


        auth.GetRequestToken();


        Console.WriteLine("Get PinCode from here.");
        Console.WriteLine(auth.GetAuthorizeUrl());
        Console.Write("PinCode：");
        string pin = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

        auth.GetAccessToken(pin);


    Console.WriteLine("AccessToken: " + auth.AccessToken);
    Console.WriteLine("AccessTokenSecret: " + auth.AccessTokenSecret);
    Console.WriteLine("UserId: " + auth.UserId);
    Console.WriteLine("ScreenName: " + auth.ScreenName);


        Console.WriteLine("yours status.");
        string status = Console.ReadLine();
        parameters.Clear();
        parameters.Add("status", auth.UrlEncode(status));
        Console.WriteLine(auth.Post("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml", parameters));
    }
}
```

Then you can use yours token and token secret for next .

Comment: i changed my application to read and write, but i am not able to post any updates , no error nothing of that sort,

Comment: can u tell me the steps involved in making an application register

Comment: i tried like these.first i build one application.after debuuging it ,i used the url of that local host to enter url in twitter api,then agian i used that urls,access tokens .i am bit confused how can we access tokens right then.

Comment: yes , I have also tried it and failed at first .  then , I have deleted my app and follow the below steps； 1：register as read/write ;  2: get pincode  3: get token and token secret 4: create post data (there is too many solution in the internet) 5: post data.  then succeed at last.

Comment: I havent get this error , have you input yours correct CONSUMER_KEY  and CONSUMER_SECRET ?

Comment: in console application i was asked to go to one url ,after typing that url i got this error msgThe request token for this page is invalid. It may have already been used, or expired because it is too old. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

Comment: I think you have got the pincode at before?  or u do start from my step 1?  if you have token you no need to request once more...

Comment: My sample is from a new account , and you have set it into read&write .  Then you got the CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET to fetch pincode

Comment: ya got it thank u very much for u r patience , can we do the same for asp.net web application.

Comment: ya got it thank u very much for u r patience , can we do the same for asp.net web application.ONE RROR the name parameteers does not exist in current context

Comment: No thanks .In my web application , I also use this method.   I met the same error as you , and take my many hours  -,-